# Xcode what's the difference between "Other Linker Flags" vs "Other_LDFLAGS"

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6

I have an app that crashes on build.

I'm told to set the "Other Linker Flags" to -ObjC. Fine.. but

in Xcode's Build settings, I don't see "Other Linker Flags", I see "Other_LDFLAGS".

So, what is the difference, and how do I change from one to the other if necessary?

A picture is worth.... so.. what I'm told I need:

[image]

and what I have:

[image]

Comment: Forgot to say, 10.8.2, Xcode 4.5.1

Comment: Why don't you put an image with some more details showing which tab is selected and all. I think both are the same.

Comment: OTHER SHOULD BE UPPER CASE

Answer (score 35, accepted):

These are the same thing. One is a synonym for the other. If you click on the Quick Help in the inspector in Xcode 4.5 when you have "Other Linker Flags" selected, it will tell you that it sets the "OTHER_LDFLAGS" setting. "Other Linker Flags" is the human-readable version, and `OTHER_LDFLAGS` is the actual variable name that the linker uses.

Comment: Is there a way to switch to the Human readable version? (After the last few days, I'm feeling human).

Comment: When you have the project or target build settings displayed, choose "Show Settings Titles" or "Show Settings Names" from the "Editor" menu to switch between them.

Comment: "click on the Quick Help .." A GREAT TIP after all these years, thanks!