# xcode c++ sqlite3 symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, sqlite, linker, xcode4.4

Hi I want to use sqlite in c++ project in xcode 4

now i am getting this error

> > Ld /Users/jayb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EMS-bpigynlzjbrescadebhoiupqmtkg/Build/Products/Debug/EMS normal x86_64
> >         cd /Users/jayb/Documents/Developement/EMS/EMS
> >         setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.8
> >         /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk -L/Users/jayb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EMS-bpigynlzjbrescadebhoiupqmtkg/Build/Products/Debug -F/Users/jayb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EMS-bpigynlzjbrescadebhoiupqmtkg/Build/Products/Debug -filelist /Users/jayb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EMS-bpigynlzjbrescadebhoiupqmtkg/Build/Intermediates/EMS.build/Debug/EMS.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/EMS.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -o /Users/jayb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EMS-bpigynlzjbrescadebhoiupqmtkg/Build/Products/Debug/EMS
> >
> > Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
> >       "_sqlite3_close", referenced from:
> >           _main in main.o
> >       "_sqlite3_errmsg", referenced from:
> >           _main in main.o
> >       "_sqlite3_open", referenced from:
> >           _main in main.o
> >     ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
> >     clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

and i found that is linker problem
it may fix with compiler option -lsqlite3

but, how can i add that option in Xcode??????

I use "Run" button on xcode 4.4 to compile my project.
i am not compiling in terminal window.

this is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sqlite3.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{   
    sqlite3 *db;
    int rc = sqlite3_open("EMSDB", &db);
    if (rc) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        exit(0);
    }
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Opened Database successfully\n");
    }

    sqlite3_close(db);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I was getting the similar error : I did following in my case:

```
#import <sqlite3.h>
```

[image]

Comment: You are a genius, you have NO IDEA how long I’ve been trying to compile SQLite3 with C++, WEEKS man — their site is USELESS, I’ve tried Linux windows Mac and was about done trying. THANK you!

Answer (score 6):

I found the way, 
wish it helps someone looking for the same solution.
now it builds correct and i can see the output

woops, I cannot post image yet :(

from the xcode build settings,
you can find a tab called (Linking)
and on the Linking tab
there are field call 'Other Linker Flags'
i simply added the -lsqlite3 for both Debug, and Release

cheers

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with xcode.  Look for `linker` settings or `compiler` settings and add the `-lsqlite3` there.

Perhaps this page helps: [Xcode what's the difference between "Other Linker Flags" vs "Other_LDFLAGS"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13022084/xcode-whats-the-difference-between-other-linker-flags-vs-other-ldflags)

LDFLAGS are passed to the linker.  CFLAGS are passed to the compiler.

Comment: Thank you for the information, If anyone know how to do that in Xcode 4.3 enviroment, would be much appriciated

Answer (score 0):

It is require to link libsqlite3.dylib in your project. That can be done in
Linked Frameworks and Libraries and add libsqlite3.dylib.

for reference follow:
[xcode sqlite3 libsqlite.dylib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392649/xcode-sqlite3-libsqlite-dylib)